# Migrating VPS Windows Server 2012 R2 system (settings, applications, ...) to Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2012, vps, windows-server-2016, migration

Need to upgrade Windows Server 2012 R2 host on VPS cloud provider to Windows Server 2016.

I cannot do it in-place. The only way to upgrade is to backup the system somehow, reset the VPS with new Windows Server 2016 system and then restore the old system settings (that is system settings, applications, firewall settings, ...).
The VPS is just simple application server with some utilities and database.

I've searched the internet but haven't found a definitive answer as how to do it. Is it even possible? The only option I've found is to use Windows Server backup to restore files and probably registries and for anything else windows server migration tools?

Comment: The only "upgrade" is an in place upgrade. The only other option is to install and configure the application on another host that has the required operating system.

Comment: **I've searched the internet but haven't found a definitive answer as how to do it.** - That's because there isn't one. You need to install the applications and roles on the "new" server and restore the data.

Comment: Thanks fro comments. That's what I thought.